# Let $n$ be an even number. Prove that $D_n/Z(D_n)$ is isomorphic to $D_{n/2}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

Let $n$ be an even number. Prove that $D_n/Z(D_n)$ is isomorphic to $D_{n/2}$.

To avoid confusion say:
$$D_n=\{a^ib^j:i\in\{0,1\}, j\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}, ba=ab^{-1}\}.$$
Through some calculation we obtain that:
$$Z(D_n)=\{e,b^{n/2}\}$$

I feel like this uses first isomorphism theorem, but I can't figure out the correct homomorphism $\phi$ where $\phi(D_n)=D_{n/2}$ and $\text{Ker}\ \phi=Z(D_n)$.

Having $\text{Ker}\ \phi=Z(D_n)$ just means that $e$ and $b^{n/2}$ are the only elements mapped to $e$ in $D_{n/2}$.

Comment: Consider $a$ and $b$. They generate the group $D_n$, so if you can decide where they end up, the rest of the group follows. Where would you think it natural for $\phi$ to send them?

Answer (score 0):

We can see that $o(bZ(D_n))=n/2$, and that $D_n/Z(D_n)=\langle \bar b\rangle\langle \bar a\rangle$, where $\bar b = bZ(D_n)$ and $\bar a = aZ(D_n)$. Now by the presentation, since $b^a=a^{-1}ba=b^{-1}$, we get that $\bar b^{\bar a} = (\bar b)^{-1}$, which means $\langle \bar a\rangle$ acts Frobeniusly on $\langle \bar b\rangle$, and that's it.